# JavaScript : Find Captcha on a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon, captcha, recaptcha

I,am working on Captcha decode/break Firefox extension and I want to find captcha field on a page if it exists. I want to make a generic thing so that when ever a page is loaded, I get the captcha image.In short, Whenever a page is loaded, It checks for a captcha and if there, It gets its image.
An approach i was trying is that to find text 'captcha' on a page and then img tag if exist,can any one plz tell me a better solution that can run on max sites.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are "max sites"?

Comment: Most people on this site are not going to be interested in helping you do this because it doesn't sound like you're planning to use it for any ethical purpose. Captchas are designed specifically to defeat the kind of program you are talking about writing. I suggest you do your own research or pay someone to do it for you.

Comment: max sites here doesn't refer to any specific site...i only meant that the solution can run on max number of sites...in short a generic approach that runs on all sites...hope i gets clear

Comment: That's not to say it's not an interesting problem from a technical point of view, but I think in order to have a discussion on the matter that will help anyone out, you are going to have to come here with more work done on the problem than what you have presented.

Comment: @NateC-K, may be u r right, But actually i m not using it for any enehical purpose, I m just collecting captchas

Comment: Well, I suggest you choose some sites, start looking at their HTML, and see how you would find the captcha for each one. See if a pattern emerges.

Comment: @NateC-K Previously i have been doing this. But then i thought to go for a permanent solution if possible. The comon thing i looked on the captcha sites is that they have used the word 'captcha'...that's why i thought to search for text 'captcha' and then find the img...But thanks for u help though

Comment: *Finding* the captcha on a web page is, bar-none, the simplest part of defeating them.  If you are having trouble locating them on the page, I anticipate you'll have one heck of a time writing the appropriate code to *decode* the captcha.  Some of them are too complex even for people to read.  There are professional hackers working on these kinds of things non-stop, and still not able to read all captchas.  Being a developer who regularly uses captchas to protect forms, the only advice I have for you is: **STOP** and find a new project.

Comment: Thanks for ue help...I guess i should stop searching for it..as it is not a technical thing...sorry guyz for any inconvenience

Answer (score 1):

Saadsaf,

In one of your comments you mentioned that:

> "...may be u r right, But actually i'm not using it for any enehical purpose, I'm just collecting captchas"

*Collecting Captchas is pretty much a useless task.*

**How Captchas Work:**

The way a Captcha works is that the user enters the characters in the image, and then submit a form - at which time the characters entered are compared to those in the image.  If the two sets of characters match perfectly, a 'Pass' condition is declared and the guarded process is allowed to continue.

The characters in the Captcha image are generally not stored anywhere that the user has access to, otherwise there would be a severe security issue for Captchas.  Most commonly, Captchas will be compared server-side so that the client has as little access to the character string as is possible.

**Why collecting Captchas is a poor idea:**

If you were to "collect" captchas for use on your sites, you would have to look at each and every one (thousands, if you figure out your code to collect them for you) and then somehow store the correct characters corresponding to each image for later use.

Between writing code to find you Captchas and then going through them all manually to correctly read the characters in each one, you will waste weeks or months of your life away.

**What to do instead:**

If you are interested in using Captchas on your sites to protect forms and prevent spam and abusive robots, your best bet is to learn how to create your own custom Captchas.  There are *endless* resources at your disposal for just such a thing, including YouTube, Google, Stack Overflow, and more.

**Where to start:**

Hop on Google and search "How to create a Captcha".  That is a good start.  Other useful search terms might be "Custom Captcha", "PHP Captcha", "JavaScript and PHP Captcha"...  Try the same searches on YouTube.  Search for "Captcha" here on Stack Overflow.

Good luck.  I hope you have only the best of intentions in mind when using this site.